# How to validate operators in a simple calculator vb program?

Tags: vb.net

So I've been trying to do a calculator program in Visual Basic (shouldn't be too bad, I think). So far I got everything down and tested the operators individually. What I'm trying to do is to have the equals sign be able to determine which operator to use and go with it according to the button pressed for operator. I thought maybe if/else or switch/case could work, but I'm either getting addition first (it's the first in the choices) or nothing at all

Maybe I'm validating the wrong variable perhaps. I thought maybe that as an example:

```
if btnEquals.Text = "(insert operator sign here)" Then 
   {insert operator statement here}
```

on an if/else or case would do it, but it's simply not. I have checked in SO for any similar issue in VB, but most are for another language. I know I have to do something to ensure that the buttons coincide with the logical statements

Basically: How do I make the "=" button in the calculator program do the right arithmetic operation when the "+", "-", "/", "*" buttons are pressed? I tried if/else and case/switch and it's not logically giving the right answers.

*Edited to clarify for other users.*

Thanks in advance!

Comment: please edit your question to make it clearer. can't get your point.

Comment: do you want to create a simple calculator program? or similar to calculator program? hmm

Comment: I'm doing a calculator. I have everything so far, but I want the "=" sign to give the result depending on the arithmetic operator the user presses. So if the "+" button was pressed, the nthe "=" does the add function. If the "/" button is pressed, then the division arithmetic function is done. Same with "-" and "*" buttons 

I tried using if/else or switch/case and for some reason it doesn't work

Answer (score 0):

Already found an easy way to do it and it worked, it was simpler than I thought and was pulling my hair for no reason. Just for future reference. I just added a type char variable and with each arithmetic button (+,-,*,/) assign the arithmetic symbols to the variable and then use if/else or case switch in the "=" button to validate that variable.

Anyone with higher rank, you can go ahead and close this one. Thank you!